# Display an array of strings in a webform when Container.DataItem is already bound to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method ListDescription() that returns an array of strings. I want to display the result of the method in a webform. The problem is that Container.DataItem is already bound to a database.  I want to display the contents of the list on different rows. For example I have <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "title")%>, so under each title I want to display different elements of the list.

So I have:

```
     public  string[] ListDescription()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        {
            string x = SplitDescription(i)[0];
            result.Add(x);
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

And I tried

```
<div class="content_text">   
     <br />               
      <h5><small><%#ListDescription()%></small></h5>      
       </div>
```

but no luck. I want to display the whole array and not just one element in it.

I had:

```
   <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")%>
```

but I split the description into two strings and they can now be found in the 
public  string[] ListDescription()

Comment: Ended up creating a new dataset with two new columns with the different parts of the string instead. So it is solved for me now.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need  call DataBinder.Eval, you can directly write Container.DataItem on databinding..

.aspx

```
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%#Container.DataItem%><br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rpt.DataSource = ListDescription();
        rpt.DataBind();
    }
   private object ListDescription()
    {
        return new string[] {"a","b","c" };
    }
```

Comment: Yes but the repeater is already bound to the database. Is that a problem? Or can I have several <asp:repeater> on the same page

Comment: is datasource object is a datatable ?

Comment: what is rpt? I thought it was a dataset so I instanciated a new dataset, but then I can't find rpt.DataSource.